# Trying to get dev test lab VM username used in Artifacts Run Powershell script

Tags: azure, azure-vm, azure-devtest-labs

We have a artifacts created
"Clone a Git Repo" - Clones the PS1 script from git hub
"Run Powershell" run the  PS1 script.
These artifact is linked to Formulae.

On creating a new VM, the Formulae is applied to run which runs the PS1 script.
Tried to a use the below powershell ps1 script to send mail once the formulae is run.

PS1 script

```
...
...
##Send mail to the User email
$ipV4 = Test-Connection -ComputerName (hostname) -Count 1  | Select -ExpandProperty IPV4Address
$emailId = $env:UserName+"@gmail.com"    
$body = "<html>
            <body>
                Hi $emailId, </br>
                </br> 
                Your VM $ipV4 is ready to access. <br/>
                Thanks,</br>
                Digital Engagement Team
            </body>
        </html>"
Send-MailMessage -To $emailId -from *** -Subject "Azure VM $ipV4 is Ready" -SmtpServer ****** -port 25 -Body $body -BodyAsHtml
```

I tired to do this but the script is failing to send message may be becauseof `$env:UserName` is not valid. How can I get the VM username as parameter to PS1 so that I can append gmail.com and send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to make it uppper-cased for it to find the variable.  Check the documentation for [accessing variables through the environment:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#access-variables-through-the-environment)

> Notice that variables are also made available to scripts through
> environment variables. The syntax for using these environment
> variables depends on the scripting language.
>
> **The name is upper-cased**, and the . is replaced with the _. This is
> automatically inserted into the process environment. Here are some
> examples:
>
> - Batch script: %VARIABLE_NAME%
> - PowerShell script: $env:VARIABLE_NAME
> - Bash script: $VARIABLE_NAME